# Custom keyboard using double-key shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm using an English keyboard; however, I sometimes need to type in Ukrainian. Unfortunately, I don't know the Ukrainian keyboard layout, so I made myself a phonetic keyboard using Javascript (I just type in a text box).

However, this is... less than optimal. However, as far as I know, I can't use Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator to create a systemwide replacement. Why?

The Ukrainian alphabet has 33 letters, so, in order to spell phonetically, some letters need to be represented by 2 Latin letters. (For example, `я` corresponds to `ya`).

Is there anyway to detect when these two letters are pressed sequentially, and replace them with a single letter? (There's no need to worry about me wanting to type `y` and `a` instead of `ya` - the letters of the combinations are rarely seen together [ie. I've never had this issue in ~5 years]).

Comment: in the windows setting> add Ukrainian keyboard . then run 'osk' (on screen keyboard). you'll see the Ukrainian keyboard layout. .. Is that what you looking for?

Comment: Not really - as a matter of preference, I use a phonetic keyboard. It's much quicker for me.